Is there a weight limit on silver ring for men
I have read a fatawa where the weight of silver for a ring for men should not exceed 4 grams.
https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/136575/wearing-a-ring-which-is-heavier-than-4-35g/
But I could not find any daleel for this fatawa. Is this fatawa correct? If yes, I would like to know it's daleel.

The fatwa is correct from the viewpoint of Hanafi fiqh, other schools of thought have different views on the matter. The evidence for it is stated in the fatwa itself, although the proper citation of the hadith is missing, it is:

أن رجلا، جاء إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وعليه خاتم من حديد فقال ‏‏ ما لي أرى عليك حلية أهل النار ‏‏ فطرحه ثم جاءه وعليه خاتم من شبه فقال ‏‏ ما لي أجد منك ريح الأصنام ‏‏ فطرحه قال يا رسول الله من أى شىء أتخذه قال ‏‏ من ورق ولا تتمه مثقالا ‏‏
A man came to the Prophet [SAW] and he was wearing an iron ring. He said: "Why do I see you wearing the jewelry of the people of Hell?" He threw it away, then he came and he was wearing a brass ring. He said: "Why do I notice the stench of idols from you?" So he threw it away, and said: "O Messenger of Allah, what should I use?" He said: "Silver, but it should not equal a Mithqal."
— Nasai etc.

A mithqal is around 4.25 to 4.375 grams, see What is the amount of nisab for Zakah?
